# lapply not working with my own variable

Tags: r

I created this custom function of mine here:

```
generate_portfolio <- function(price_list_w_returns, initial_AUM){
  price_list_w_returns1 = lapply(price_list_w_returns, transform, USD_portfolio = initial_AUM*cum_returns )
}
```

where initial_AUM is something that someone can change to whatever number he or she wants.

USD_portfolio in this case is a new column that i am trying to create and cum_returns is an existing column. price_list_w_returns is a list of dataframes with similar columns and rows.

The error i am getting is:

```
 Error in eval(substitute(list(...)), `_data`, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'initial_AUM' not found
```

Comment: Can you show us the an example of the code that gives that error? To me this seems like an error from the wrong use of `lapply`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is of not fully correct definition of lambda-function in `lapply`. You are trying to pass an argument, which is not defined, to the function. Please see below how it is solved in `generate_portfolio2`:

```
# simulate list of data.frames
price_list_w_returns <- replicate(10, data.frame(id = 1:10, cum_returns = abs(rnorm(10)/ 10)), simplify = FALSE)
str(price_list_w_returns)

## Not run: 
generate_portfolio <- function(price_list_w_returns, initial_AUM){
    price_list_w_returns1 = lapply(price_list_w_returns, transform, USD_portfolio = initial_AUM * cum_returns )
}

generate_portfolio(price_list_w_returns, 2)

## Error in eval(substitute(list(...)), `_data`, parent.frame()) : 
##  object 'initial_AUM' not found 
## End(Not run)

generate_portfolio2 <- function(price_list_w_returns, initial_AUM){
  lapply(price_list_w_returns, function(x) {
    x$USD_portfolio = initial_AUM * x$cum_returns
    x
  })
}

generate_portfolio2(price_list_w_returns, 2)
```